# UIGestureRecognizer SIGSEGV Crash

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, segmentation-fault

I'm having this issue, on iOS 7 only, in my app. We encounter about a thousand of these crashes a day, but we have never seen it internally and have no clear ideas of what could be causing it. Anyone have any insight?

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x116c9f9e
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '', reason: ''

libobjc.A.dylib 0x39c62b26 objc_msgSend + 6
UIKit 0x31c74bbb -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 1139
UIKit 0x3200083d ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 49
UIKit 0x31c3c00b _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 219
UIKit 0x31c3a753 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 283
UIKit 0x31c73419 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 773
UIKit 0x31c72dbf -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
UIKit 0x31c4879d -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 197
UIKit 0x31c46fa3 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7099
CoreFoundation 0x2f49c183 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
CoreFoundation 0x2f49b653 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 207
CoreFoundation 0x2f499e47 __CFRunLoopRun + 623
CoreFoundation 0x2f404c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
CoreFoundation 0x2f404a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
GraphicsServices 0x340f8283 GSEventRunModal + 139
UIKit 0x31ca8049 UIApplicationMain + 1137
MyApp 0x0004be27 main (main.m:18)
libdyld.dylib 0x3a16fab7 start + 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem has happened long before this code runs and crashes. You're probably trying to talk to an object that has been released. But you're not going to get much of a clue here as to what that object is...

Comment: Do you use KVO? Might be a missing observer...

Comment: @Nick: Did you find the cause of this crash? I am facing the same issue right now on back button press

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for solution to the same thing. I've just isolated where this happens. I had an enormous scrollview and I add gesture recognizer on it as follows:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[_backgroundFrameView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

The crash log in Hockey app is the same as provided by @Nick Locking, however it clearly says where crashing:

> Reason: objc_msgSend() selector name: handleSingleTap:

It happens only on iOS 7.X versions and I'm completely unable to reproduce it on my own. _backGroundFrameView has exclusiveTouch = YES, and MultipleTouch = NO.